# Why are photons released from high-voltage electricity through a near vacuum?

Tags: electricity, photons

I read an answer to what is inside a typical vacuum, and it suggested neutrinos from Space, and vapor from the container. So, maybe they add to this effect...

But why are photons released from high-voltage electricity passing through a near vacuum?

Comment: What actual example of photons being generated in a vacuum by high-voltage electricity are you thinking of?

Comment: @BenjaminFranz Like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLyCiovM9ko)

Comment: Summary of above video: transparent tube (~.5 meters long, ~10 cm diameter) with embedded anode and cathode (each at opposite end, about 5cm from tube-end); hole at bottom of tube presumably to cause 'vacuum' at '29 inches of vacuum'; 10 kV DC passed between electrodes (see at 6:10 mins for effect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'vacuum' in this case is really a low pressure gas (with a pressure of 10 to 30 mm of mercury). The light show is caused by ionization of the gas by the electric current.